# Angular 4 Node Mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js, angular, express

I am a newbie when it comes to web development . I am currently working to get a real time web project up and running . I have a ms sql server 2014 working in my workplace and have installed node.js/ and used express generator to generate out an application . I have used mssql node module to connect and retrieve data from mssql server and it works.Although, Things that are confusing to me at this point:

how do i add angular 4 into the equation to help with the frontend  development?i have already done npm install --save anular/cli but do not know where to start regarding creating input forms with drop downs whose values are to retrived from the DB .

my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();



// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

my index.js (i tried to create a connection with myssql and display a table in the index.html jade file)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    GetData(function(recordset)
    {
  res.render('index', {projects: recordset })
  });
});

function GetData(callback )
{
    var sql = require ('mssql');

    const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
    database: 'xxxxx',

    options: {
        encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 
    }
};


    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err)
    {

        var request = new sql.Request(connection);
        request.query('select * from Project_Type' , function(err, recordset)
        {
          callback(recordset);
        });

    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

Some more questions:
Is this the right place to start a sql connection ? or should i put in in the app.js file

and other advice as to how to setup the environment and angular to properly speak with the db would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to expose usernames and passwords in the public facing JS? perhaps you want a server back end that will do the DB connection for you and provide this information through rest calls to your client side AngularJS application.

Comment: this was just for experimentation purposes , just so that i can verify i can read data from node in the sql server

Comment: You can use this seed project https://github.com/oualidmaz/mean-seed and change mongo with your sql